# How to set Authorization only in one end point in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication

In WCF service i have added one more Binding (webHttpBinding). Now i want to apply Basic Authorization with these new web behavior. Previous end point and bindings should work without effect any changes is it possible I have one implementation with Same contract and function.

Comment: Each endpoint in WCF has a binding, and we can set a different security mode for each binding, for webHttpBinding we can use https to protect it.

Answer (score 0):

In principle every binding can have it's own security setting. webHttpBinding seems to have three security levels to choose from (None, Transport and TransportCredentialOnly) see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/security-of-webhttpbinding. If you are careful not to touch the security settings of your other bindings in your other endpoints they should not be affected by introducing a new endpoint with a new binding.